# Dynamically sort with linq C#

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I would like to sort a datagridview with multiple actions.

I explain myself: I've a dictionnary with a key and a value. 
The value is a string with ASC or DESC and I'd like to sort everything with this strategy:

```
string sort=String.Empty;
sort+=".OrderBy(c=>c.Value)"; ==> the first one in my list
foreach(var column in list) 
{
    if(column.Value=="DESC")
        sort+=".ThenByDescending(c=>c.Value)";

    if(column.Value=="ASC")
        sort+=".ThenByAscending(c=>c.Value)";
}
```

`List<Formule> list=ListFormules.Where(f=>f.Identificator==null)`==> It's my problem

I don't know how to change my string to work in my query.
Have you an idea or a better way to do that?

Comment: Check out dynamic linq. [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

Comment: +1 @scheien - should probably be expanded to a full answer..!

Comment: @AlexG It is impossible to even count all the answers where this was already explained...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post my comment as an answer due to comments.

You should check out dynamic linq.

Scott Guthrie has a detailed blog post about it. [Link](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

Comment: You may want to expand your answer somewhat, however, as link-only-answers are considered largely unhelpful due to possible link-rot.